# CSS calc() percentage rest division multiplication

Tags: html, css

hey there it is posible to calc this on css?

100% - 650px / 2 * 100 / 100%

i have a div contaniner that grow with resize window so in this container i have an iframe that max-width must be 650px and i want to mantain aligned on center of container, use a left for that reason i use the /2 to determine the width of left and right over space i try to use this but doesn't work:

```
left: calc(((100% - 650px) / 2) * (100 / 100%));
```

any help would be apreciated
thanks

full css code:

```
#video_externo {
                background: #222222;
                text-align: center;
                width: $c;
                position: relative;
                padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
                padding-top: 25px;
                height: 0;
                iframe,
                video,
                object,
                embed {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    height: 100%;
                    max-height: 400px;
                    width: 100%;
                    max-width: 650px;
                    border: 0;
                    @media (min-width: 768px) {
                        left: calc((100% - 650px / 2 * 100) / 100%);
                    }
                    @media (min-width: 1024px) {
                        left: 0.7575757575757576%;
                    }
                    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
                        left: 9.375%;
                        top: 7.894736842105263%;
                    }
                    @media (min-width:1500px){
                        left: 20.72072072072072%;
                        top: 19.20115495668912%;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Solved Working CSS:

```
#video_externo {
                background: #222222;
                text-align: center;
                width: $c;
                position: relative;
                padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
                padding-top: 25px;
                height: 0;
                iframe,
                video,
                object,
                embed {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    height: 100%;
                    max-height: 400px;
                    width: 100%;
                    max-width: 650px;
                    border: 0;
                    @media (min-width: 768px) {
                        left: 50%;
                        transform: translateX(-50%);
                    }
                    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
                        top: 7.894736842105263%;
                    }
                    @media (min-width:1500px){
                        top: 19.20115495668912%;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Alternative Solution With FlexBox:

```
#video_externo {
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                background: #222;
                position: relative;
                padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
                padding-top: 25px;
                height: 0;
                iframe {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 100%;
                    max-width: 650px;
                    height: 100%;
                    max-height: 400px;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 50%;
                    transform: translateX(-50%);
                }
            }
```

just have troubles with top: i think is for the padding to forces to show 16:9 video

Comment: so you want to align the iframe with max-width 650px in the center of a container? You probably don't need calc, you could just do `transform: translate(-50%); left: 50%;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This calculation seems to be wrong, almost for (100 - 100%) I don't understand. But it seems that you need a solution for perfectly center horizontally one element. It's easiest like this:

```
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
```

This aligns perfectly without calculations and without pre-known the size of the elements. You can see working:

```css
.border { width: 100%; height: 500px; position: relative; border: 1px solid black;}
.center { width: 200px; height: 150px; background-color: #f00; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%); }
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <div class="center">
    Centered
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are welcome, it's easiest than you think in first moment :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler solution using CSS flexbox.

e.g.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #fff;
}

  .container > iframe {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 650px;
    /* just to show the element */
    background: #09c;
    padding: 100px 0
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

You'll want to remove the `background` properties and the `padding` on the `<iframe>` obviously but this is the way forward.

This method also allows you to be much more flexible in your entire layout pattern as flexbox supports lots of other features that front-enders and the like have wanted for many years.

For further reading I'd recommend reading the following:

- [CSSTricks guide on flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [Mozilla Developers Network flexbox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)
- [Scotch guide on flexbox](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties)

Note that there is also no need to use `calc` anywhere, you won't need `calc` at all when using flexbox but it could take some time to get used to.